# Minimal objects in category theory

Tags: category-theory

The notion of initial object in category theory, corresponds to the notion of minimum element in a pre-ordered set. Is there a notion of **minimal object** in category theory (that would correspond to the notion of minimal element in a pre-ordered set)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One categorical way of characterizing minimal objects of a poset is as an $x$ such that if there's a morphism $y\to x$ then it's an isomorphism. This isn't a particularly common phenomenon in category theory, except for the case of *strict initial objects,* an initial object which is also minimal in this sense. Note that initial objects in a category don't have to be minimal, since even if some $x$ maps into an initial object $0,$ not all maps $x\to y$ must factor through $0$ (unlike in the case of a poset.)

There is also a generalization of a poset with *enough* minimal objects (where every object is comparable to some minimal, as is important for instance in the opposite of the poset of ideals of a ring.) This is the idea of a category with a *weakly initial set*, a set of objects such that each object of the category admits a map from some object in the set. These sets are very important in adjoint functor theorems, although again, such objects don't need to be *minimal* in any particular sense in general.

Comment: For an example of an initial object which is not minimal in this sense: the initial object $\mathbb{Z}$ of $\mathbf{Ring}$.  Then for example, there is a map $\mathbb{Z}[x] \to \mathbb{Z}$ which sends a polynomial to its constant coefficient; this map is certainly not an isomorphism.

Comment: There is now a [nLab page](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/minimal+object) for this concept, for which the earliest listed reference is Wißmann's [Minimality Notions via Factorization Systems and Examples](https://arxiv.org/abs/2202.05701).